# Concurrent Dictionary AddOrUpdate not adding, updating and returning correctly

Tags: c#, dictionary, concurrentdictionary

I am using concurrent dictionary addOrUpdate in C#. The problem is that this dictionary is not mainting the whole dictionary(list) instead of this it only addOrUpdate last record into the dictionary and that record found multiple times in dictionary; i traversed through it in foreach loop.

```
//Volunteer Class
public class VolunteerMessage
{
    #region Variables
    public int UserId;
    public string UserName;
    public double Longitude;
    public double Latitude;
    public string Message;
    public string LocationTime;
    #endregion

    #region Public Methods
    public VolunteerMessage(string longit, string latit, string msg)
    {
        Message = msg;
        try
        {
            Longitude = Convert.ToDouble(longit);
            Latitude = Convert.ToDouble(latit);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
        }
    }
    #endregion
}

private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<int, VolunteerMessage> _volunteerdict;
_volunteerdict = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, VolunteerMessage>();
var vappProDataObj = new VolunteerMessage(null, null, null);

try
{
    for (var i = 0; i < dsVolunteers.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        vappProDataObj.UserId = Convert.ToInt32(dsVolunteers.Tables[0].Rows[i]["UserID"]);
        vappProDataObj.UserName = dsVolunteers.Tables[0].Rows[i]["UserName"].ToString();
        vappProDataObj.Longitude = Convert.ToDouble(dsVolunteers.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Latitude"].ToString());
        vappProDataObj.Latitude = Convert.ToDouble(dsVolunteers.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Longitude"].ToString());
        vappProDataObj.LocationTime = dsVolunteers.Tables[0].Rows[i]["LocationTime"].ToString();
        _volunteerdict.AddOrUpdate(vappProDataObj.UserId, vappProDataObj, (k, v) => vappProDataObj);

        Console.WriteLine(" Location Updaetd for " + vappProDataObj.UserName);
    }
    LogManager.Instance.WriteMessage("Volunteers List refreshed", "RefreshVolunteersList", null);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    LogManager.Instance.WriteMessage("Volunteers List refreshing failed", "RefreshVolunteersList", e);
}
```

and the loop is here:

```
VolunteerMessage itemFound = null;
double distance = 0;
foreach (var item in _volunteerdict)
{
    distance = GetDistanceFromLatLonInKm(Convert.ToDouble(e.Latit), Convert.ToDouble(e.Longit), Convert.ToDouble(item.Value.Latitude), Convert.ToDouble(item.Value.Longitude));

    if (distance <= 1000)
    {
        itemFound = item.Value;

        if (!itemFound.Equals(null))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(itemFound.UserName + " Is at " + distance + " from Location");
            _xmppConn.SendPrivateMessageXmpp(itemFound.UserName, e.Mesag);
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("No User found near message area");
    }
}
```

Please tell me what I am doing mistake?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `AddOrUpdate` does exactly what it says, it adds an item if it *doesn't exist*, or *updates* it if it does. You're only creating a single instance of `VolunteerMessage`, and you're probably using the same `UserId` between loop iterations, hence you end up only with the last value updated.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov How can i maintain all records into the dictionary instead of last one? Please give solution

Comment: Don't re-use the same `UserId`. Hand out a new id on each iteration. This probably means a new instance of `VolunteerMessage` each time.

Comment: It appears as though you are giving it the same key so it just replaces it all the way until the end, vappProDataObj.UserId = Convert.ToInt32(dsVolunteers.Tables[0].Rows[i]["UserID"]); Rows[i]["UserId"] will equal "Object". Use Rows[i]["UserID"].ToString()

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov My requirement is to maintain dynamic keys and values against keys. How do i do this?

Comment: @StephenBrickner No. Even if it is the same class instance the Id will be overriden every loop. It will be added to the dict with it's unique key. The problem is (as both answers already say) that he changes the value of the dictionary so that all values are the same because he only created only on instance. The only way this code would work is if `VolunteerMessage` is a struct - but I think its a class.

Comment: @Vera rind, what I'm saying is Row[i][anything] without ToString() will give you "Object", so every key is replacing itself. MyDictionary[Object] =

Comment: VolunteerMessage  is a class its not a struct; I am updating my question please check

Comment: @StephenBrickner ??? Sorry, I don't understand you (maybe it's because I'm not a native speaker). The key is int. He don't need to use `ToString()` because he uses `Convert.ToInt32()`. Int is struct. This struct is copied by giving it to `AddOrUpate`. There is no chance to change that key in the dict. The next loop run will override the int value `UserId` of the only object but the key in the dict has nothing to do with this property.

Comment: @ZiaUlMustafa If it's class you've two answers that tell you what's wrong with your code.

Comment: @Vera rind, I added an answer below to demonstrate what I am saying.

Comment: @StephenBrickner Where it is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are only making one instance of `vappPropDataObj` and are editing its values rather than making many instances of this object, each with their own unique values. As a result, your dictionary has many keys, all of which point to the same single `vappPropDataObj` object.

Try writing something like this instead:

```
private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<int, VolunteerMessage> _volunteerdict;

try
{
    for (var i = 0; i < dsVolunteers.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        var vappProDataObj = new VolunteerMessage(null, null, null);

        vappProDataObj.UserId = Convert.ToInt32(dsVolunteers.Tables[0].Rows[i]["UserID"]);
        vappProDataObj.UserName = dsVolunteers.Tables[0].Rows[i]["UserName"].ToString();
        vappProDataObj.Longitude = Convert.ToDouble(dsVolunteers.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Latitude"].ToString());
        vappProDataObj.Latitude = Convert.ToDouble(dsVolunteers.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Longitude"].ToString());
        vappProDataObj.LocationTime = dsVolunteers.Tables[0].Rows[i]["LocationTime"].ToString();
        _volunteerdict.AddOrUpdate(vappProDataObj.UserId, vappProDataObj, (k, v) => vappProDataObj);

        Console.WriteLine(" Location Updaetd for " + vappProDataObj.UserName);
    }
    LogManager.Instance.WriteMessage("Volunteers List refreshed", "RefreshVolunteersList", null);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    LogManager.Instance.WriteMessage("Volunteers List refreshing failed", "RefreshVolunteersList", e);
}
```

Comment: That should be no problem if `VolunteerMessage` is a struct - but I think it's a class.

Comment: @Verarind Ah, that's true. I didn't think of that. As you say though, it's unlikely to be a struct.

Answer (score 1):

You're making updates to a single `VolunteerMessage` and expecting it to become many objects when it enters the dictionary.

You'll need to create a new `VoluteerMessage` *in the loop* to make several copies of the message, otherwise all of the entries in your dictionary will point to the same single message that had its properties changed many times over.